# Nvidia imaginaire: CUDA out of memory

Tags: python, memory-management, pytorch, nvidia

I am using Nvidia imaginaire for a University project and have the problem, that I always get the error:

```
"RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1024.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.95 GiB total capacity; 1.54 GiB already allocated; 189.50 MiB free; 2.40 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"
```

I am a little bit lost what else I can do to free space than decreasing the batch_size and even decreasing my resolution.

Here are some infos of my GPU and CUDA:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.63.01    Driver Version: 470.63.01    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 35%   32C    P8    17W / 170W |    355MiB /  4039MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I am using this config .yaml file: https://github.com/NVlabs/imaginaire/blob/master/configs/projects/fs_vid2vid/face_forensics/ampO1.yaml

Could it be that 4GB of VRAM are not enough? Can I somehow prevent the system to reserve 2.40 GiB for PyTorch?

Thank you in advance and best wishes!

Comment: 4GB is not much. You can try to turn off anything else (like chrome tabs), that might free up some space

Comment: I also tried that. I am trying it on Pop OS with 1920x1080 resolution and nothing else opened. :/

Comment: then it sounds like you need to use your cpu

Comment: How is it possible to use CUDA just with CPU?

Comment: CPU's are just not optimized for the work (will take like 10x or more time), but they can run this: https://community.esri.com/t5/imagery-and-remote-sensing-questions/how-force-pytorch-to-use-cpu-instead-of-gpu/td-p/1046738

Comment: I did not know that, I will try that out, thank you. Besides that I guess there is no other possibility?